# Mongo $addToSet an Array

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a working query:

```
$offenses = \App\LawCase::raw(function ($collection)  {
                return $collection->aggregate([
                    [
                        '$match' => ['active' => true, 'type' => 'criminal', 'current_offense_literal'=> ['$exists' => true]]
                    ],
                    [
                        '$group' => ['_id' => '$current_offense_category', 'offense_literals' => ['$addToSet' => '$current_offense_literal']]

                    ]
                ]);

            });
```

I just want to add an additional value to the addToSet above. For example Each current_offense_literal also has a current_offense_literal_value and I would like to add that along with current_offense_literal.

What i tried:

```
$offenses = \App\LawCase::raw(function ($collection)  {
                return $collection->aggregate([
                    [
                        '$match' => ['active' => true, 'type' => 'criminal', 'current_offense_literal'=> ['$exists' => true]]
                    ],
                    [
                        '$group' => ['_id' => '$current_offense_category', 'offense_literals' => ['$addToSet' => ['$current_offense_literal'=>['$push'=> '$current_offense_literal_value']]]]

                    ]
                ]);

            });
```

But I am getting: 
Unrecognized expression '$current_offense_literal'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing this,

```
$offenses = \App\LawCase::raw(function ($collection)  {
                return $collection->aggregate([
                    [
                        '$match' => ['active' => true, 'type' => 'criminal', 'current_offense_literal'=> ['$exists' => true]]
                    ],
                    [
                        '$group' => ['_id' => '$current_offense_category', 'offense_literals' => ['$addToSet' => ['current_offense_literal'=>'$current_offense_literal', 'current_offense_literal_value' =>'$current_offense_literal_value']]]

                    ]
                ]);

            });
```

Comment: Thank you. That was it.